# Find a link that contains a specific word using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I have this link:

```html
<a href="/location/santa-clara/3fce50c4f3f9793d2f503fc145585090">Santa Clara, California</a>
```

How can I use BeautifulSoup to find specifically this link that includes the word location `"location"`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can do it with a simple ["contains" CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
soup.select("a[href*=location]")
```

Or, if only one link needs to be matched, use `select_one()`:

```
soup.select_one("a[href*=location]")
```

And, of course, there are many other ways - for instance, you can use [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) providing the `href` argument which can have a [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) value or a [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
import re

soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("location"))
soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and "location" in href)
```

Comment: is re.compile() taking "location" and turning it into a regular expression? basically just abstracting away having to right the regex myself?

Comment: @MorganAllen note that string "location" is also a valid regular expression. In this case, `BeautifulSoup` would just match `href` values where there is a `location` substring. Glad to be helpful.

Comment: Or `soup.select_one("a[hre^=/location]")` if you want hrefs starting with /location

Comment: The selector requires quotes around the string to be searched. I.e.: 
`soup.select("a[href*='location']")` for 'contains' and 
`soup.select("a[href^='location']")` for 'starts with'. 

Also: note the slight typo (missing `f`) in Padraic Cunningham's comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a list comprehension over the `a` tags, which could be much easier to understand if you don't want to deal with CSS. If there are hundreds of tags to search through, it's much faster as well.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div>
    <a href="/domains/example">More information...</a>
    <a href="">Empty</a>
    <a>No href</a>
    <a href="/location/santa-clara/3bac">Santa Clara, California</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# to return a list of all tags containing 'location' in its href
res = [a for a in soup.find_all('a') if 'location' in a.get('href', [])]

# for the first matching tag
res = next((a for a in soup.find_all('a') if 'location' in a.get('href', [])), None)
```