# BeautifulSoup .find() capturing too much text (how do I narrow it down?)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

wondering how to target the "Switch" text on the below html:

```
    <div class="product_title">
                <a href="/game/pc/into-the-breach" class="hover_none">
                            <h1>Into the Breach</h1>
                        </a>
                        <span class="platform">
                            <a href="/game/pc">
                                                    PC
                                                </a>
                        </span>
        </div>
<div class="product_data">
    <ul class="summary_details">
                        <li class="summary_detail publisher" >
                <span class="label">Publisher:</span>
                <span class="data">
                                        <a href="/company/subset-games"  >
                                                    Subset Games
                                                </a>
                                    </span>
            </li>
                                    <li class="summary_detail release_data">
                <span class="label">Release Date:</span>
                <span class="data" >Feb 27, 2018</span>
            </li>
                                                                                <li class="summary_detail product_platforms">
                        <span class="label">Also On:</span>
                        <span class="data">
                                    <a href="/game/switch/into-the-breach" class="hover_none">Switch</a>                                                </span>
                    </li>
                                                    </ul>
</div>
```

so far I am capturing the "Also On:" text as well (with a lot of spaces) with this code:

```
self.playable_on_systems_label.setText(self.html_soup.find("span", class_='platform').text.strip() + ', ' + self.html_soup.find("li", class_='summary_detail product_platforms').text.strip())
```

how do I capture (in this case) only the "Switch" text?

FYI - for the first half of the statement (capturing the "PC") text works fine just not the "also on" text

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Your query is getting the entire span element with `class="summary_detail product_platforms"`, which is going to include all the text starting from "Also On:" until "Switch." Try something like `.find('a', href=re.compile("^.+switch.+$"))` or alternately (using CSS) `.select("a[href*=switch]")` [(solution from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252434/beautifulsoup-to-find-a-link-that-contains-a-specific-word)

Answer (score 0):

you can use BeautifulSoup `select()` function to navigate the the "Switch" text, check this code!!!

```
rom bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="product_title">
<a class="hover_none" href="/game/pc/into-the-breach">
<h1>Into the Breach</h1>
</a>
<span class="platform">
<a href="/game/pc">
                                                    PC
                                                </a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="product_data">
<ul class="summary_details">
<li class="summary_detail publisher">
<span class="label">Publisher:</span>
<span class="data">
<a href="/company/subset-games">
                                                    Subset Games
                                                </a>
</span>
</li>
<li class="summary_detail release_data">
<span class="label">Release Date:</span>
<span class="data">Feb 27, 2018</span>
</li>
<li class="summary_detail product_platforms">
<span class="label">Also On:</span>
<span class="data">
<a class="hover_none" href="/game/switch/into-the-breach">Switch</a> </span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = soup.select('.summary_detail.product_platforms .hover_none')[0].text.strip()
print(text)
```

Output:

```
Switch
```