# Drop part of a soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning how to use beautifulsoup. I managed to parse the html and now I want to extract a list of links from the page. The problem is that I am only interested in some links and the only way I can think of is to take all the links after a certain word appears. Can I drop part of the soup before I start extracting? Thank you.

This is what I have:

```
# import libraries
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

# specify the url
quote_page = 'https://econpapers.repec.org/RAS/pab7.htm'

# query the website and return the html to the variable page
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

print(soup)

#transform to pandas dataframe
pages1 = soup.find_all('li', )
print(pages1)

pages2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "papers": pages1,
    })

print(pages2)
```

And I need to drop the upper half of the links in  `page2` and the only way to differenciate the ones I want from the rest is a word that appears in the html, that is this line "`<h2 class="colored">Journal Articles</h2>`"

EDIT: I just noticed that I can also separate them by the begining of the link. I only want the ones that start with "`/article/`"

Comment: Can you share what have you tried ?  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was trying to edit it as text but it doesnt work because it is a class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup' so I dont know what I can try. Not sure if I should try to transform it to text and cut it and then find a way to make it a soup again. Or edit it while being this type

Comment: Are these links in anchor tag ?

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be various ways to get all the href starting with "/article/". One of the simple ways to do this would be :

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re
import ssl

# specify the url
quote_page = 'https://econpapers.repec.org/RAS/pab7.htm'

gcontext = ssl.SSLContext()

# query the website and return the html to the variable page
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page, context=gcontext)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#print(soup)

# Anchor tags starting with "/article/"
anchor_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("/article/"))

for link in anchor_tags:
    print(link.get('href'))
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252493/1338382) would be helpful as well. And, go through the [quick start guide of BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start), it has a very good and elaborative examples.

Answer (score 3):

As well using css_selector:

```
# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
#print(BeautifulSoup.prettify(soup))

css_selector = 'a[href^="/article"]'
href_tag_list = soup.select(css_selector)
print("Href list size:", len(href_tag_list)) # check that you found datas, do if else if needed

href_link_list = [] #use urljoin probably needed at some point
for href_tag in href_tag_list:
    href_link_list.append(href_tag['href'])
    print("href:", href_tag['href'])
```

I used this reference web page which was provided by another stackflow user:
[Web Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

NB: You will have to take off the list the "/article/".